# Sequential insert ids on mass inserts in InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

Can anyone confirm that an InnoDB database in MYSQL will generate AI IDs sequentially when inserting more than row in a single insert statement using PDO (PHP)?

I'm working on a project where the user can upload a excel document which is insterted into the db by the rows in the excel file.  These documents can be one row to ~10,000.  For speed I would like to be able to insert these in blocks, if not all in one query.

From what I've read it looks like it is safe to use the last insert id minus number of inserts to get the block of id's that were inserted.

Has anyone had any experience with this not being 100% secure, or any information on the subject.

If it helps here's roughly how I would be inserting it  (I would be doing this in sets of 500)

*Simplified Insert Example:*

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($rowData['Name']); $i++) {
    $insetPlaceHolders[":name$i"]=$rowData['Name'][$i];
    $insetPlaceHolders[":email$i"]=$rowData['Email'][$i];
    $insetPlaceHolders[":password$i"]=$rowData['Password'][$i];
    $insetPlaceHolders[":employeeId$i"]=$rowData['EmployeeId'][$i];
    $insetPlaceHolders[":startDate$i"]=$formData['StartDate'][$i];
    $appendQuery[]="(:name$i,:email$i,:password$i,:employeeId$i,:startDate$i, {$_SESSION['companyId']})";
}
$appendQuery=implode(',',$appendQuery);
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (name, email, password, custom_id, hire_date, company_id) VALUES $appendQuery");
$sth->execute($insetPlaceHolders);
```

Comment: someone else can insert one single row in there at the same time = bad

Comment: sequentially, yes... consecutive, no, there's no guarantee about that, unless you can lock the table.

Comment: I'd say that if you are concerned in having ids sequentially, there is something wrong with your schema

Comment: The reason why I'm worried about having them sequentially is because I use the id's to generate emails that go out to the logins that were created.  I could just use the data that I inserted on successful insert, which seems like a better way to go anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the proper way to do this.

You would want to have two tables.  One table holds metadata about the document, and one table holding row information for the document.

You would then insert a record into the metadata table, and retrieve the value of the id that was generated for you.

You would then insert your detail records, including the metadata id as a reference to the document.  Then, it does not matter if the id's are contiguous.  This is how a relational database stores this sort of information.

Your schema would represent something like this:

```
create table metadata (
    metadataid int autoincrement primary key,
    filename varchar(50) not null,
    ...
);

create table details (
    detailid int autoincrement primary key,
    metadataid int not null references metadata(metadataid),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Well, I'm not actually looking to store the file, it's just so the user can create a set of logins for the company.   Currently this is done by reading the file in a temp directory using PHPexcel.

Comment: @user2240634 then why are you trying to store the data in a database?  And why do you care about continuity of ID's?

Comment: Good point.   The excel sheet is just a way for the user to create a lot of "accounts" at once.    I was looking to get a set of ids back so that I could pass them to a previously created email function, however, it seems like sending the emails using the data that I inserted (on successful insertion) is probably a better way to go, seeing as the passwords are going to be encrypted anyways.